# Jquery save toggle state on live click and window setTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle, state, settimeout

I was wondering. How to save an event state ( toggle() ) while I am getting data with ajax and using
window setTimeout to keep the data fresh.

I have this code to refresh window every 10 seconds

```
window.setTimeout("load_data()", 10000);
```

And on the div where data is loaded and toggle() event takes place

```
$('#maindiv #click').live('click', function(event) {
  $('#togglediv').toggle();
});
```

Every thing works fine, except that when window is loaded every 10 seconds then the toggle state is reset.
How can I fix that or maybe a workaround solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should starting accept the community's answers. please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work only with client side technology, you can use cookies for that. Take a look at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/.

You can also work with url parameters, but I guess cookies would be a better approach.

Comment: Yeah that was my initial thought, I thought maybe it could be done without cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can pass toggled = 0 or toggled = 1 as parameters to your URL when you refresh the page,
and have them stored as javascript variable, by printing them through your backend script ( PHP or ASP.NET).